# what is the function that acts like SYSTEM(const char *) and takes no const char but a dynamic produced query

Tags: c, linux

i want to write a program that will create a file  by passing the string to the shell at  program executes . this can be done by the system()
 but  i want  to use this function , for many arguments in a loop . using system(char *) its giving error . is there  any other way

i tried a lot     plz somebody  help me   .

Comment: This should be very simple and straightforward - post your code so that people here can help you to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Conversion from `char*` to `const char*` is implicit and will work. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`const char *s` has nothing to do with what it expects to find in `s`.  It is a promise to you, made by the function, that the function will not modify the contents of `s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `system` as mentioned and programmatically modify the `char *` that you pass it, or you can use a function of the `exec` family (`exec`, `execve`, `execvp`, etc... depending on what is available on your system).

Please read the man of `system` and `exec` carefully: they do not do exactly the same thing. You may want to have a look at the man of `fork` as well if you go the `exec` way.

Comment: Unlike the other answers mentioning `exec`, at least this one is right. Still somewhat unrelated to OP's problem. If one doesn't understand even the basics of C, using `exec` will be a lot harder than using `system`.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're looking for execv.  The behavior isn't quite identical, but it's close.  See also execl.  They share the same man page.

Comment: Unrelated to OP's problem which is simply misunderstanding of C types and function arguments.